# Monodevelop + ASP.NET + Windows Auth on WindowS?

Tags: asp.net, window, monodevelop

Is it possible to use Windows Auth when using Monodevelop? Whilst i understand this is more a framework question, it's MonoDevelop that fires up the web server.

I'm looking to get away from VS, as it's quite resource hungry (and wallet). However, i have an MVC3 project which i would like to play with in it, but can't get Windows auth working the same (doesn't seem supported, according to docs).

Is it possible to configure MonoDevelop to fire up Cassini or IIS?

Cheers,
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to launch Cassini or IIS via MD's configuration options, but MonoDevelop's open-source, so you could add that feature if you want. The people in the MonoDevelop IRC channel should be able to help you get started if you want to do so.

Also, note that MD on Windows targets .NET by default - maybe it wouldn't be hard to alter xsp so that Windows auth works when it's running on .NET.

Comment: Thanks for this, thought that might be the case. Time to figure out how to compile MonoDevelop on Windows it is!